# Not all the values in DNN model are quantized after using tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT

Tags: python, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to change the .pb format of a DNN model to .tflite and I would also want to quantize all the weights and biases. When using the following code, the weights get quantized in 8 bits, but the biases are still float.

I have already used the last version of tf-nightly. The code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph_def_file = "DNN_S.pb"

converter=tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(graph_def_file,input_arrays,output_arrays,input_shapes)

converter.target_spec.supported_ops=[tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]

converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

tflite_model = converter.convert()

open("model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

How can I change the format of biases to 8 bit integers, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do post training quantization in TensorFlow Lite you are not actually converting the entire model to 8-bit.

Instead the converter is creating a hybrid model where the weights are quantized but the rest of the model is left in floating points. This technique has shown to give large model compression benefits while reducing the accuracy drop from quantization.

To create a true quantized model you would have to look at quantization aware training.